# AWS Credentials Missing when pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Answered**: I misspelled `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` when setting the environment variables for Heroku. I left off the second S.

---

I'm building a Rails 4 application, and using Paperclip and AWS for image uploading. Every time I try to upload an image, I get `AWS::Errors::MissingCredentialsError (Missing Credentials` in the Heroku logs.

In my gem file I have

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

In my production.rb file I have

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

I have an initializer named aws-sdk.rb that only has this in it:

```
AWS.config({
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  })
```

And in my relevant model file I have

```
has_attached_file :picture, 
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
            :bucket => 'MyBucketName',
        :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
        },
    styles: {
        thumb: '100x100>',
        square: '200x200#',
        medium: '300x300>'
      }
```

I didn't think that I needed to explicitly include the s3 credentials with the has_attached_file method? I tried it anyway. Still not working.

When I run `heroku config` it shows my access key, key id, and bucket names correctly.

I have no idea what's going wrong.